Thread local static variables gives seg fault when compiling with clang
I am trying to write a simple random utility function with a static generator and distribution. All functions and variables are static and therfore shared across the program. My program is not currently using threads but I would like it to be able to later. Therfore I want to declear my generator as a thread_local variable for performance reason.
I am trying to write a simple random utility function with a static generator and distribution. I want these variables to be thread_local, which works fine when compiling with gcc. With clang however, the program gives a seg fault when initializing the generator.
#include<random>
#include<chrono>

class RandomTest
{
public:
    RandomTest() = delete;
    static void  initialize(); 
  
private:   
 
    thread_local static std::mt19937                           s_generator;
    thread_local static std::uniform_real_distribution<double> s_distribution;
};
thread_local std::mt19937                           RandomTest::s_generator{};
thread_local std::uniform_real_distribution<double> RandomTest::s_distribution{0.0, 1.0}; 


void RandomTest::initialize()
{
    s_generator.seed(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
}

int main()
{    
    RandomTest::initialize();   
}

The line that seg fault is this s_generator.seed(...) function. Now I know using the current time for seeding is a dubious idea at best, but it works fine for my application for now and other types of seeds also gives a seg fault. I found a SO post saying the variables need to pass through main to be initialized, but global variables instead initializes their own copies. So i tried having them as global variables, but with the same result for clang. I have also had problems with thread_local variables in other external libraries in my code
I am using C++17 and version 14.0.4 of clang. Also I am using Windows 11, with a Ryzen 7 4000 cpu.
My questions are: Is there a bug with clang and thread_local? Is the code provided something that should work? If not what can be changed. Are there any compiler flags or other things that may fix the problem?
Thanks is advance

Side note : seeding a random generator with time is a bad practice. Use std::random_device for that.  And a question why don't you make your all Random class a threadlocal class (more control over lifetime) and also reusable without pre-baked thread affinity

I mentioned time seed in my post. I will look into thread_local classes

Provide the driver code also as a [mcve]

Also mention the clang version used and c++ version used.

Doesn't crash here

I have seen very few examples of this other places so maybe there is something wrong with my system or distribution of clang

Please don't remove includes from your examples. You're creating more work for anyone who'd want to run this.

What OS are you using?

I am using windows 11. Also updated the post with some more system info

How did you install Clang? Clang 14 is quite outdated, the latest version is 18.

To be honest it is quite a while a go. I think it was from source forge. Next course of actions for me now is to reinstall clang

Are you using clang or clang-cl? If clang which standard library are you using?

@AlanBirtles They mentioned that they're using clang 14.0.4 and c++17 after I asked for the same in one of the comments.

@user12002570 doesn't necessarily mean they're not using clang-cl

@AlanBirtles Yeah that part they can still clarify.

I am using clang, not clang-cl

I'd start with updating Clang. Clang on Windows works in tandem with either MSVC or MinGW (needs one of them for their standard libraries). Choose your installation method depending on which of the two you like more. If you prefer MinGW, install Clang from MSYS2 (do this, then run pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-clang) (it comes with MinGW). If you prefer MSVC, install Clang from here (use ...-win64.exe), and make sure to install MSVC (normally you'd install the whole VS).

I reinstalled clang they way you suggested and it works fine. I guess it was just an outdated version that was causing the problem
